# Android Speech recognition: negative numbers

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having some problems with my app.
It's an app that asks user to enter 2 numbers by speech recognition, one by one.
If i say six and seven it will multiply 6 and 7 and tell me the result.
Even decimals will work (6.2, 7.5).
But when i say minus eight or negative eight, my app immediately crashes, and isn't even asking for another number, just crashes.
In logcat it says "`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "minus 8"`"
so i guess it enters 'minus 8' instead of '-8'.
My question is, what can i do to solve this?
Here is the whole activity:

```
    package cannon.gaming.physicsdroidvoice;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    private Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
    private boolean mIslistening;
    int forza, m, a;
    double mass, acc, mares;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        forza = 0;
        m = 0;
        mass = 0;
        a = 0;
        acc = 0;
        mares = 0;
        final String abc = "Welcome to PhysicsDroid!";
        final String abcc = "What do you need?";
        final String abccc = "Force, Velocity, Mass, Acceleration, Distance, Time, Temperature, Work, Density, Info, or Exit?";
        final String abcccc = "Just tap the screen and speak. When you are done, tap the screen again.";
        final String abccccc = "Can you repeat please?";
        final String force = "Which force equation would you like to use?";
        final String exit = "Thank you for using PhysicsDroid, see ya!";
        final String one = "First one: F=m times A. Second one: F=p times A. Or third one: Fg=G times m1m2 over r squared?";
        final String ma = "What is the mass of object in kilograms?";
        final String am = "What is the acceleration of object in meters per second squared?";
        final String mnum = "What the fuck!";
        final TextToSpeech home = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                   //DO NOTHING
                }
            }
        });
        new Timer().schedule(
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                            home.speak(abc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                            home.speak(abcc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                            home.speak(abccc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                            home.speak(abcccc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                    }
                },
                1000
        );
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
        this.getPackageName());
        class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener
        {

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
            {
                //Log.d(TAG, "onBeginingOfSpeech");
            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech()
            {
                //Log.d(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error)
            {

                //Log.d(TAG, "error = " + error);
            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
            {
                //Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle results) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "onResults"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                CharSequence cs1 = "Force";
                CharSequence cs2 = "force";
                CharSequence cs3 = "Exit";
                CharSequence cs4 = "exit";
                CharSequence cs5 = "First";
                CharSequence cs6 = "first";
                CharSequence cs7 = "times";
                CharSequence cs8 = "equals";
                if(forza == 1 && m == 0 && a == 0)
                {
                    if(String.valueOf(matches).contains(cs5) || String.valueOf(matches).contains(cs6) || String.valueOf(matches).contains(cs7) || String.valueOf(matches).contains(cs8))
                    {
                        home.speak(ma,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        forza = 0;
                        m = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if(m == 1 && forza == 0 && a == 0)
                {
                    if(String.valueOf(matches).matches(".*\\d.*"))
                    {
                        home.speak(am,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        mass = Double.parseDouble(matches.get(0));
                        m = 0;
                        a = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        home.speak(mnum,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    }
                }
                else if(a == 1 && m == 0 && forza == 0)
                {
                    if(String.valueOf(matches).matches(".*\\d.*"))
                    {
                        acc = Double.parseDouble(matches.get(0));
                        mares = -mass * acc;
                        String mare = String.format("The force is %.2f", mares);
                        home.speak(mare,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        a = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        home.speak(mnum,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    }
                }
                else if(String.valueOf(matches).contains(cs1) || String.valueOf(matches).contains(cs2) && forza == 0 && m == 0 && a == 0)
                {
                    home.speak(force,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    home.speak(one,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                    forza = 1;
                }
                else if(String.valueOf(matches).contains(cs3) || String.valueOf(matches).contains(cs4) && forza == 0 && m == 0 && a == 0)
                {
                    home.speak(exit,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    new Timer().schedule(
                            new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                    System.exit(1);
                                }
                            },
                            4000
                    );
                }
                else
                {
                    home.speak(abccccc,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
                // matches are the return values of speech recognition engine
                // Use these values for whatever you wish to do
            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
            {

            }

        }
        SpeechRecognitionListener listener = new SpeechRecognitionListener();
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);
        RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity);
        rlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                boolean mIsListening = false;
                if (!mIsListening)
                {
                    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                }

                else
                {
                    mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
                }
            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is the part where it's crashing after 'minus 8'

```
else if(m == 1 && forza == 0 && a == 0)
            {
                if(String.valueOf(matches).matches(".*\\d.*"))
                {
                    home.speak(am,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    mass = Double.parseDouble(matches.get(0));
                    m = 0;
                    a = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    home.speak(mnum,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
```

as you can see from the code above, matches is what user spoke.
Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that STT (speech to text) is translating what you say to text, and it doesn't understand signs. This kind of operation is call [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) ( Natural Language Processing ) where depending on the strategies you use you can understand, classify and translate what was said to what you need.

To solve your problem you should relly on some simple strategies like Regexes to see if on the returned `matches` it has the negative or minus word and then convert your number.

Using your piece of code would be something like:

```
String extractedNumber = matches.get(0).replaceAll("[^0-9.]*","");
mass = Double.parseDouble(extractedNumber);
if ( matches.get(0).matches(".*((minus)|(negative)).*") ){
     mass *= -1;
}
```

What I'm doing is replacing everything that isn't a number, then I verify if in the text exists the words `minus` or `negative` and if so I just multiply the number by -1 making it negative.

Comment: Glad that I could help! :)

Comment: i'm having one more problem now and i think you can help me.
sometimes my app doesn't understand me very well and when i say seven, it hears [7, seven, 70]. That's exactly what it hears, i know because i set toast pop up with the 'matches' in it, as i said previously, matches is what user said.
and most of the numbers work, but when i say two it's [tube, tune, 2, to]
and it chrashes.and i've noticed it's because the first word is tube, if it was 2, then tube,tune,etc... it would work i believe.
is there any way to eliminate all words except the important ones like, minus, negative, point?

Comment: That line on the code I showed to you already do that `matches.get(0).replaceAll("[^0-9.]*","");` it eliminate all the words! The other line do exactly the other thing check it on the `matches` does have the words you needand from there you do some operation. So for your case, to add some more roles to it just add the word you need like `if ( matches.get(0).matches(".*((minus)|(negative)|(point)).*") ){` Explaining this it is a regular expression that checks for `anything(.*) then minus word OR (|) negative word OR (I) point word and anything(.*)

Comment: As you are not using any technic to know what is said you have to rely on rules. Bunches of regex or even indexOf for that words and from it do what you need on the IF statements.